# Numpy Optimization Issue

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a process done with some for loops looping over the entire array, but I'm looking to do this correctly using numpy such that I can leverage the speed optimizations:

I have x rows, and a pandas dataframe with columns for start_period, which can be and usually is negative, and frequency. I also know that there will be n total periods. The goal is to construct a matrix which indicates when the adjustments will happen. So for example:

| id | start_period | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -20 | 12 |
| 1 | -5 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

And say n=12, the expected result would be an array like this:
[[4],[1,7],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]

One thing I've tried so far is:

```
res = df[["start_period"]]).values
res = np.pad(res ,((0,0),(0,n-1)))
freq = df[["frequency"]].values
for i in range(1,n):
    res[:,[i]] = res[:,[i-1]] + freq
a = [[x for x in y if x < n and x >= 0] for y in res]
final_matrix = np.zeros((len(a),0))
for i in len(a):
    final_matrix[i,a[i]] = 1
```

But that last list comprehension takes a good bit of time given the size, and the for loop ends up creating far too wide an array given most of the frequencies are 12 (it's number of months) and the n is usually several hundred. It does seem to give the correct results, I'm just hoping I can do something more using numpy optimizations around the for loop and list comprehension.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how you go from the table to the expected result? If obtaining `a` is the goal, why are you showing us `final_matrix` as well? You're also initialising it with one of the axes to have size 0 and there is an error in `for i in len(a)`.

Comment: I have difficulty as well understanding what is this all about

Comment: Apologies this is my fault I was trying to generalize a problem I'm working on at work without including any actual code or business problem I'm trying to solve and I didn't take enough time to create a reproducible example with proper names so it would make sense.